# Обработать данные полученные через API в Python'e

Tags: python

Нужна помощь, через API стороннего сервиса, при помощи метода GET я получаю некую информацию с помощью следующего кода, пример которого я взял из документации к API:

```
def nextChar(str):
    return ("&", "?")[len(str) == 0]

protocol    = "https://"
host        = "ссылка на апи"
token       = "токен"
key         = "ключ"
request_headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Authorization": "AccessToken " + token,
    "X-User-Authorization": "Basic " + key
}
name    = "187"
size    = ""
sort    = "asc"
page    = ""
if not (name):
        print("\"name\" parameter is required");
        exit(1);
path = "/1.0/batch/" + name + "/shipment"
params = ""
if size:    params += nextChar(params) + "size=" + size
if sort:    params += nextChar(params) + "sort=" + sort
if page:    params += nextChar(params) + "page=" + page
print("params: ", params)
url = protocol + host + path + params
response = requests.get(url, headers=request_headers)
print("Status code: ", response.status_code)
print("Response body: ", response.text)
```

В принте выводится список словарей, в каждом словаре ключи повторяются и имеют разные значения. Мне необходимо каким-то образом записать в другой файл получение значения определенных ключей. Пробовал просто скопировать список и пройтись по нему циклом в отдельном файле .py, но получаю ошибку, т.к одно из значений ключа не обрамлено кавычками и нет такой переменной. Пример полученного списка после исполнения кода:

```
Response body:  [ {
  "barcode" : "номер",
  "human-operation-name" : "статус",
  "in-mmo" : false,
  "manual-address-input" : false,
  "mass" : 23,
  "mass-rate" : 5900,
  "mass-rate-with-vat" : 7080,
  "pre-postal-preparation" : false,
  "recipient-name" : "ФИО",
  "region-to" : "город",
  "renewal-shelf-life" : false,
  "returned-partial" : false,
  
}
```

И таких словарей в списке много. Для решения задачи, мне нужно записать значения ключей "recipient-name" и "barcode" в отдельный файл. Каким способом я могу это сделать?

Comment: Сервис вам возвращает невалидный json, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Сервис возвращает список из словарей, я к сожалению в питоне новичок, не пробовал записать как-то содержимое response в json файл. Пробовал только циклом пройтись по response.text, не вышло, потому что значения "false" не обрамлены кавычками

Comment: Используйте модуль json для преобразования текста в нормальный объект питона. https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-json.html